# Are there themes for aspnet mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, themes

I'm searching for themes designed to be used with aspnet mvc3; i've found MvcContrib but download link is now empty. Can anyone help me in finding themes designed to run with the Razor engine?

Comment: There may be a way to incorporate webforms style themes to a MVC project, but the best/cleanest way to do it would be to simply use custom CSS and HTML in your views.  Doing it that way opens up your project to ANY theme/layout you can find on the web.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET MVC3 doesn't come with any pages, so you won't find any themes for it. You have to build your own HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough i wouldn't recommend doing so but you could use the .skin files

Answer (score 0):

Try using an html5 boilerplate. There's a bunch of layouts u can use.

Answer (score 0):

I based mine on the default Twitter Bootstrap layouts, very easy to build a site from them.